# Apache 2.2 Slow serving static files on Windows 2003

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, performance

I'm having problems with a Windows 2003 Server which is running Apache 2.2.

The performance of the server seems really bad and as a test just trying to load a 10kb file takes a while to load in the browser.

Does anyone have any tips for improving the performance?

my httpd.conf has this set:

```
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 500
MaxRequestsPerChild 0
KeepAliveTimeout 4
Timeout 60
HostnameLookups off
```

And the /extras/httpd-mpm.conf

```
#
# Server-Pool Management (MPM specific)
# 

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
#
# Note that this is the default PidFile for most MPMs.
#
<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
    PidFile "logs/httpd.pid"
</IfModule>

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#




<IfModule !mpm_winnt_module>
<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
LockFile "logs/accept.lock"
</IfModule>
</IfModule>

#
# Only one of the below sections will be relevant on your
# installed httpd.  Use "apachectl -l" to find out the
# active mpm.
#

# prefork MPM
# StartServers: number of server processes to start
# MinSpareServers: minimum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxSpareServers: maximum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxClients: maximum number of server processes allowed to start
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          30
    MinSpareServers       30
    MaxSpareServers     30
    MaxClients          1000
    ThreadsPerChild 1024
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# worker MPM
# StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
# MaxClients: maximum number of simultaneous client connections
# MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          30
    MaxClients          1000
    MinSpareThreads      30
    MaxSpareThreads      30 
    ThreadsPerChild      1024
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# BeOS MPM
# StartThreads: how many threads do we initially spawn?
# MaxClients:   max number of threads we can have (1 thread == 1 client)
# MaxRequestsPerThread: maximum number of requests each thread will process
<IfModule mpm_beos_module>
    StartThreads            10
    MaxClients              50
    MaxRequestsPerThread 10000
</IfModule>

# NetWare MPM
# ThreadStackSize: Stack size allocated for each worker thread
# StartThreads: Number of worker threads launched at server startup
# MinSpareThreads: Minimum number of idle threads, to handle request spikes
# MaxSpareThreads: Maximum number of idle threads
# MaxThreads: Maximum number of worker threads alive at the same time
# MaxRequestsPerChild: Maximum  number of requests a thread serves. It is 
#                      recommended that the default value of 0 be set for this
#                      directive on NetWare.  This will allow the thread to 
#                      continue to service requests indefinitely.                          
<IfModule mpm_netware_module>
    ThreadStackSize      65536
    StartThreads           250
    MinSpareThreads         25
    MaxSpareThreads        250
    MaxThreads            1000
    MaxRequestsPerChild      0
    MaxMemFree             100
</IfModule>

# OS/2 MPM
# StartServers: Number of server processes to maintain
# MinSpareThreads: Minimum number of idle threads per process, 
#                  to handle request spikes
# MaxSpareThreads: Maximum number of idle threads per process
# MaxRequestsPerChild: Maximum number of connections per server process
<IfModule mpm_mpmt_os2_module>
    StartServers           2
    MinSpareThreads        5
    MaxSpareThreads       10
    MaxRequestsPerChild    0
</IfModule>

# WinNT MPM
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in the server process
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum  number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    ThreadsPerChild      1000
    MaxRequestsPerChild    0
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please look for this directives in httpd.conf and uncomment them:

```
EnableMMAP off
EnableSendfile off
```

Also set this in httpd-mpm.conf

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    ThreadsPerChild         32
    MaxRequestsPerChild  10000
    Win32DisableAcceptEx
</IfModule>
```